# New laptop, windows 7, Outlook 2007 installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

A friend of mine has purchased a new laptop (Toshiba) with Windows 7 installed and has also purchased Outlook 2007 and atttmped to install it - the install worked ok, but I think he may have selected Exchange server when installing the first time - now it will not start, displaying message like "Your Microsoft Exchange Server is unavailable "

Outlook 2007 should have been configued for Pop3 as he has a hotmail account, but Outlook will not load "offline" and despite me de-installing, re-installing, running repair, I cannot get it to load to a point where I can add a new email account.

If any one has any ideas on this, I would apprecaite the help

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete the profile (from the Mail control panel), so you can set it up again for POP/IMAP.

Comment: not sure I can do this as Outlook will not load. If there is somewhere else I can ddlete this profile, could you let me know - many thanks

Comment: is this mail control panel part of the main control panel in Windows 7 ?

Comment: As he wrote, from the control panel applet "Mail".

Comment: @Bob: Yes the mail control panel applet is part of the main control panel. Go into Control Panel, double click the Mail icon, click the Show Profiles button, highlight the profile and click the Remove button. Then start Outlook and it will launch the first run wizard and you'll be able to set it up correctly.